# Convert Windows dll of C functions for use in Python in Linux

Tags: python

Is it possible to convert a Windows dll file containing C functions to something that I could use in a Python program in Linux? I'm able to call the C functions in Python in Windows, but not Python in Linux. Is there any other way I could use that dll file Linux Python?

Comment: sure just get the source for the dll and recompile it on linux as a .so file (I think) ... since the dll is compiled against windows it will only run on windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have the source code to recompile it for Linux (assuming it's even that easy), you might be able to make it work by installing the Windows version of Python in [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/).

Comment: Unfortunately, it's for a raspberry pi which I don't think can use wine.

Comment: Then I'm afraid the answer is "It's not possible." If you give us more information about what the DLL does, we may be able to suggest alternatives.

Comment: It's a DLL file containing C functions used to control a USB device (Picoscope 4227)